# Duplicate key error after an exception DoesNotExist has been raised in Django

Tags: django

I need to insert new `Candle` objects which has a datetime field option `unique=True`. To avoid validation error when creating the object I first test if I can get it with `objects.get()` and when an exception `DoesNotExist` is raised I create it. My problem is that after an exception is raised, the creation failed because a key is duplicated.

```
    try:
        Candle.objects.get(market = instance, dt = dt)

    except Candle.DoesNotExist:
        Candle.objects.create(
            market = instance,
            dt = dt,
            op = op,
            hi = hi,
            lo = lo
            cl = cl
        )
```

As you can see I try to get the candle for a specific market, which is the instance I'm working on. And it seems to work because it throws the exception.

However, when it creates the object another exception is raised for violation error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "marketsdata_candle_timestamp_key"
DETAIL:  Key (dt)=(2019-11-28 00:00:00+00) already exists.
```

My analysis is that a candle with the same `dt` field exist in another market, but it shouldn't throw a violation error because I specify `market = instance` to create the candle in the instance of the market I'm working on. And it works just fine with the `get`.

Also what I found weird is that `Candle` doesn't have a field `timestamp` since it has been renamed to `dt`. This is how my models looks like:

**models.py**

```
class Candle(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='market',
                               null= True
                               )
    dt = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
    op = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    hi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    lo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    cl = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

class Market(models.Model):
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name='exchange'
                                 )

    pair = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pair)
```

Could someone please tell me why the `create` methode doesn't work while the `get` works? and also where the `timestamp` field comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model field's `uqinue` attribute affect all table. So if you have one record with specific dt value in your table you will not able to add another one even with dictinct `market` value. Instead of `unique` on specific field try to use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#unique-together) option:

```
class Candle(models.Model):
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name='market',
                               null= True
                               )
    dt = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['market', 'dt']
```

As for `marketsdata_candle_timestamp_key` naming it's the name of DB constraint which was created when you create `timestamp`. Later you rename this field, but name of constraint was not changed and it still contains previous field's name.

BTW django has [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) shortcut  which you can use in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and solution I appreciate. Indeed I didn't used the `get_or_create` because I thought the get and the create are performed on the same fields whereas I need the get to be done only on `dt` but not on others fields that might be similar. I will try your solution, thanks again!

Comment: It works when `dt = models.DateTimeField()` otherwise I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

When you are querying using the get(), you are using two constraints ie market and dt. But when it comes to creating a record, only the dt field is checked for uniqueness. So you need to go with 'unique_together'. Within your model, you need to mention that in the Meta.

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = [['field1', 'field2']]
```